# After Webpack 5 upgrade. Refused to apply style from

Tags: webpack, single-spa

I have a single-spa setup which was working perfect when running with webpack4

After upgrading to webpack 5 I got alot of these errors:

> Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:5000/assets/css/style.bundle.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

I have googled for hours without being able to solve this.

My webpack config file is:

```
const path = require('path');
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const singleSpaDefaults = require('webpack-config-single-spa');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (webpackConfigEnv, argv) => {
  const orgName = 'ringana';
  const defaultConfig = singleSpaDefaults({
    orgName,
    projectName: 'root-config',
    webpackConfigEnv,
    argv,
    disableHtmlGeneration: true,
    // publicPath: '/',
  });

  return merge(defaultConfig, {
    // modify the webpack config however you'd like to by adding to this object
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        inject: false,
        template: 'src/index.ejs',
        templateParameters: {
          isLocal: webpackConfigEnv && webpackConfigEnv.isLocal,
          orgName,
        },
      }),
    ],
    output: {
      filename: 'root-config.js',
      libraryTarget: 'system',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      // publicPath: '/',
      clean: true,
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.css$/i,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
          type: 'asset/resource',
        },
        // {
        //   test: /\.scss$/,
        //   loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
        // },
      ],
    },
    devServer: {
      static: ['assets'],
      open: true,
      hot: true,
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        // 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff',
      },
      allowedHosts: 'all',
      historyApiFallback: true,
      // client: {
      //   logging: 'info',
      //   progress: true,
      //   overlay: {
      //     errors: true,
      //     warnings: true,
      //   },
      // },
    },
  });
};
```